# Animation: Move TextView into another container

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to move, in an anmiated way, a TextView in a LinearLayout into another LinearLayout.
However, I can't get it to move outside its container view (the LinearLayout it is in), it only moves inside this. Can someone help me to get this done? Also see the following image:
[image: textviews and linearlayouts]

I'm using the NineOldAndroids library and have tried with the ViewPropertyAnimator:

```
animate(myTextView).setDuration(500).x(?).y(?);
```

And also with:

```
animate(myTextView).setDuration(500).translationX(?).translationY(?);
```

Instead of the '?' in above I want to be able to find out the position of the LinearLayout I want to drop the TextViews in. (If it's not possible to move to a certain View by stating the View-object).

Comment: The problem isn't really clear. Doesn't the animation work? Or are the values your getting from the LinearLayout position null?

Comment: @TimKranen: I edited the question to make it a bit clearer. The animation works, but I can't get the TextView to move outside the LinearLayout it is in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What need to be done is to add "android:clipChildren="false"" to all the container layouts.