# TextView disappears after translate Animation from one linearlayout to other linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, objectanimator, nineoldandroids

I am trying to swap two text views (which are in different linear layouts) with each other.

My requirement is little similar to the one mentioned in the below link,

[Animation: Move TextView into another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019838/animation-move-textview-into-another-container)

I used ObjectAnimator of "nineoldandroids" library, but the textview is getting disappeared when it moves to other layout.

Could someone please help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Update 1:-

Now I used PropertyValuesHolder of "nineoldandroids" library to perform translate animation. After using PropertyValuesHolder, textview are visible (i.e., not disappeared) after completing animation. But the onclick function is not working after the animation.

Also I placed toast message to check the X dimension of Textviews after animation.

Then I got the following displays:-
Before Animation:-
for textview at first row & first column (i.e., tv11) :- 0.0
for textview at second row & second column (i.e., tv22) :- 0.0

After Animation:-
for textview at first row & first column (i.e., tv11) :- 240.0
for textview at second row & second column (i.e., tv22) :- -240.0

Is there anyway, to make these text views as a child for other layouts (to where they have been moved).

Please find the below code for the same:-

- **MainActivity.java:-**

  ```
  findViewById(R.id.tv22).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {

              PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", +240);
              PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", +380);
              ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(findViewById(R.id.tv11), pvhX, pvhY).setDuration(2000).start();


              PropertyValuesHolder pvhX2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", -240);
              PropertyValuesHolder pvhY2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", -380);
              ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(findViewById(R.id.tv22), pvhX2, pvhY2).setDuration(2000).start();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11)).getX()+"tv11", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv22)).getX()+"tv22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      });
  ```
- **activity_main.xml:-**

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:clipChildren="false"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp" />

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:clipChildren="false"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv11"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#4374E0" />

  <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv13"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#4374E0" />

  <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp" />

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:clipChildren="false"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv21"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#4374E0" />

  <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv22"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#4374E0" />

  <View
      android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- **Update 2:-**

Even after performing below changes, onclick is not working fine. Could someone please help me.

```
        findViewById(R.id.tv22).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11)).getX()+"tv11"+((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv22)).getX()+"tv22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  

                PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", +240);
                PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", +380);
                final ObjectAnimator changeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(findViewById(R.id.tv11), pvhX, pvhY).setDuration(2000);
                changeIn.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator anim) {                 
                        view.setScaleX(1f);
                        view.setScaleY(1f);*/                                                                                   
                        TextView testtv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11);                            
                        TextView testtv2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv22);
                        testtv1.clearAnimation();
                        testtv2.clearAnimation();
                        View v1= container1.getChildAt(1);
                        View v2= container2.getChildAt(3);
                        Log.i("childcount1 before",container1.getChildCount()+"");
                        container1.removeView(v1);
                        Log.i("childcount1 after",container1.getChildCount()+"");
                        Log.i("childcount2 before",container2.getChildCount()+"");
                        container2.removeView(v2);
                        Log.i("childcount2 after",container2.getChildCount()+"");
                        Log.i("check1","Removed Successfully");

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
                        container1.addView(v2, 1,lp);                           
                        container2.addView(v1, 3,lp);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv11)).getX()+"tv11"+((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv22)).getX()+"tv22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                changeIn.start();

                PropertyValuesHolder pvhX2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", -240);
                PropertyValuesHolder pvhY2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", -380);
                ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(findViewById(R.id.tv22), pvhX2, pvhY2).setDuration(2000).start();


            }
        });
```

Comment: Post your code what you have done till now, some screen shots will be good as well.

Comment: Hi @Techfist, I updated my question please check it.

Comment: OKay great, let me have a look

Comment: Hi @Techfist, finally I ended up using normal "TranslateAnimation" to perform translation. I know that this Animation changes the visual only, but the actual button still remains in the original position defined in xml layout. In my game, when user clicks on a button, two textviews (i.e., red color textview and blue color textview) should swap with each other. Now I am doing translation of textviews using "TranslateAnimation" and programmatically exchanging the colors for these textviews in background.